# how can i properly display dataframes on a Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, loops, pdf, r-markdown, report

I am currently working on the creation of an automated report via RMarkdown that would help to assess how students perform. I have created a that analyses some KPI for each lesson and when i am running it on R it the data frames are properly displayed on my console (cf screenshot 1 [screenshot 1 - df produced by the loop and properly displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBkRW.png).

However, when i am running the loop in the rmd file and trying to display it on the pdf report, it does not work and the data frames are not properly displayed [this is what I get when knitting my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AP55.png)

I am a new user of RMarkdown so I absolutely do not master the language and if anyone could help me it would really be appreciated.

The code for I use in the r markdown file is the following :

```
## CREATION DE LA BOUCLE/FONCTION
# Tableau par cours 
cours_subset = subset(data, select = (num_inscr_prog_ulb+1):ncol(data))
cours_subset = cours_subset[, colSums(is.na(cours_subset[1, ])) == 0]
moyenne_cours = cours_subset[5,]
cours_subset = cours_subset[-1:-5,]

# début de la boucle
for (a in 1:ncol(cours_subset)) {
  test_colonne = cours_subset[,a] #boucler sur le nombre de colonne
  nom_colonne = colnames(test_colonne[1])
  test_colonne_no_na = subset(test_colonne, !is.na(test_colonne[,1]))
  #unique(test_colonne_un[, 1])
  #unique(test_colonne_un_no_na[, 1])
  #test_colonne_un_no_na = data.frame(as.numeric(unlist(test_colonne_un_no_na)))
  
  effectif = nrow(test_colonne_no_na[1])
  count_abs = 0
  count_abj = 0
  count_ndp = 0
  count_ann = 0
  count_else = 0
  grades = NULL
  
  for (i in 1:effectif) {
    valeur = test_colonne_no_na[i, 1]
    if (valeur == "ABS") {
      count_abs = count_abs + 1
    }
    else if (valeur == "ABJ") {
      count_abj = count_abj + 1
    }
    else if (valeur == "NDP") {
      count_ndp = count_ndp + 1
    }
    else if (valeur == "ANN") {
      count_ann = count_ann + 1
    }
    else {
      count_else = count_else + 1
      grades = c(grades, valeur)
    }
  }
  
  grades = gsub(",", ".", grades)
  grades_num = as.numeric(grades)
  nombre_de_zero = length(subset(grades_num, grades_num == 0))
  moyenne_du_cours = round(mean(na.omit(grades_num)),3)
  moyenne_du_cours_sans_zero = round(mean(subset(grades_num, grades_num != 0)), 3)
  
  noms_df = c("Cours analysé", "Effectif", "NDP", "ABS", "ABJ", "ANN", "Elèves ayant passé l'examen",
              "Moyenne", "Nombre d'élèves ayant eu 0", "Moyenne sans les 0")
  valeurs_df = c(nom_colonne, effectif, count_ndp, count_abs, count_abj, count_ann, count_else, moyenne_du_cours, 
                 nombre_de_zero, moyenne_du_cours_sans_zero)
  summary_cours = data_frame(Description = noms_df, Valeur = valeurs_df)
  print(pander(summary_cours))
}
```

I have tried to simply print the data frame by using

```
print(summary_cours)
```

and it did not work. I also tried to use knitr and flextable but none of the two worked neither.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to understand what is in your preamble/ metadata section of your .RMD file and helpful to know what parameters your have called in your r code chunk https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/vignettes/pander.html

Comment: Those are my preamble/metadata section : 

---
title: "test R markdown"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
date: "2023-05-23"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
sansfont: Times New Roman
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
mainfont: Times New Roman

---

and i have not called any specific parameters in the r code chunk

Comment: Just to make sure, you did enclose your code in ```    ```{r} ...``` ``` and all to mark it as a code chunk, didn't you? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html

Comment: Yes i did,

it looks like that : ``` ```{r} my code with the for loop ``` ```